# Django Response has no content - How to debug?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, python-3.4

I am trying to add testing to my Django 1.8 application and am running into trouble with a test to make sure registration goes through successfully. I don't know how to debug to see what is wrong.

I make the following call in my code after setting up the Client.

```
class LoginTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_user_can_select_vegetarian_on_account_create(self):

        data = {'username': 'TestUser', 'password1':'pass', 'password2':'pass', 'email':'bad@email.com', 'is_admin':True}
        r = self.client.post('/register/', data)
        print(r.content)
        self.assertTrue(r.context is not None)
    print(list(User.objects.all()))
```

the `print(r.content)` just prints a blank, so nothing is coming back, although it is a response. When I look at the status code, I get a 302.

I am not sure how to see what is going wrong, so mostly I am just looking at how to debug this process. Print statements in the server code are not showing up so I am totally lost as to what is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: I should also say I have gotten server side prints to print by calling the tester with `-v 1` but I still can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I guess the 302 is supposed to tell the browser to make another request to the given URL, so everything is working as expected? The browser doesn't return another page - it tells the client to make another request. Can someone confirm?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous No, I haven't used that at all yet. I'll try that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

302 status code means redirect, if you want to see the content of that redirect you have to add "`follow=True`":

```
response = self.client.post('/register/', data, follow=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/

by the way... in order to debug what is going on I suggest you to use an IDE like PyCharm, in which you can add breakpoints and go through code step by step!

Comment: No need to use an ide to get debugging. You can do it perfectly well in the console using `pdb`.

Comment: yes, but an IDE is far more easy, features-reach and user friendly to use ;)